# How to add counts on top of bars, and percentage of fill inside bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, percentage, stacked-chart

I have some data in which each observation contains 2 factors, classes (a letter between A and E), and flag (0 or 1). After applying a group_by(classes,flag) and a summarize(frequency=n()), I get a data frame similar to this one:

```
classes <-as.factor(c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E", "E"))
    flag <- as.factor(rep(c(0,1),10))
    quantity <- c(856, 569, 463, 125, 795, 313, 1000, 457, 669, 201)
    df <- data.frame(classes, flag, quantity)
```

I managed to get the chart that I want (ordered bars, one for each level of classes, each bar filled with the proportion of flag) with this code:

```
    ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(classes, -quantity), y = quantity)) +
      geom_bar(aes(fill = as.factor(flag)), stat="identity") +
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
      labs(x = NULL, y = "Quantity", fill = "flag") +
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("firebrick","dodgerblue4"), 
      labels=c("1"="Yes","0"="No"))+
      theme(axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

However, I am not sure how to use the geom_text() to include both the total count on top of each bar, and the proportion of the fill value inside the bars.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a way to automate this, probably it's easiest to calculate proportions and sums outside the plot.

It's easier to reorder the classes outside the plot, so that your text can take over the factor-levels.

```
df$x <- reorder(df$classes, -df$quantity)
```

Next you can calculate the statistics you want. Below I assumed that if we split `df` by classes, it is always the order `flag = 0`, `flag = 1`, so we can take `x[2]/x[1]` as proportion.

```
text_df <- data.frame(
  class = sapply(split(df$classes,  df$classes), unique),
  sum   = sapply(split(df$quantity, df$classes), sum),
  prop  = sapply(split(df$quantity, df$classes), function(x){x[2]/(x[1]+x[2])})
)
```

Then we let `text_df$class` take on the same ordering as `df$x`.

```
text_df$class <- factor(text_df$class, levels = levels(df$x))
```

Then we make the plot similar to your example, remember we reordered the x-variable earlier:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = quantity)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = as.factor(flag)), stat="identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Quantity", fill = "flag") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("firebrick","dodgerblue4"), 
                    labels=c("1"="Yes","0"="No"))+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

And add two geoms for text, one for the proportion, one for the sum; both with a y-offset.

```
 +geom_text(data = text_df, 
            aes(x = class, 
                y = sum + 100, # some offset
                label = sum)) +
  geom_text(data = text_df,
            aes(x = class, 
                y = sum - 100, # opposite offset
                label = scales::percent(prop)))
```

And I think that did the trick. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Obviously I had to modify a few  things to get exactly what I wanted but your code did the trick. There is one thing to modify though. In order to get the proportion of the value flag == 1 when creating the ```text_df```, the prop column should be created like this ```prop  = sapply(split(df$quantity, df$classes), function(x){x[2]/(x[1]+x[2])})```.